# Bar Plot with more than one variables

Tags: variables, plot

I have this set of data:

> TestSystems

[1] 0013-021 0013-022 0013-031 0013-032 0013-033 0013-034
  Levels: 0013-021 0013-022 0013-031 0013-032 0013-033 0013-034

> Utilization

[1] 61.42608 64.95802 31.51387 45.11971 43.66110 63.68363

> Availability

[1] 28.92506 32.58015 11.86372 16.22164 36.23264 40.54977

> str(TestSystems)

Factor w/ 6 levels "0013-021","0013-022",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6

> str(Utilization)

num [1:6] 61.4 65 31.5 45.1 43.7 ...

> str(Availability)

num [1:6] 28.9 32.6 11.9 16.2 36.2 ...

I would like to have a plot as below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5dMq.jpg
The plot is not from R, but other software. I would like the same plot to be from R. Appreciate any help.
thanks.

Comment: Have you even try googling yet? Jes.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with below code and it works

df <- data.frame(TestSystems, Availability, Utilization)

df.long<-melt(df)

p  <- ggplot(df.long,aes(TestSystems, value,fill=variable))+ geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")

how do I display those 12 values at the top of each bar?